# Armadillo: eigs_gen for smallest eigenvalue

Tags: sparse-matrix, armadillo, eigenvalue

I'm using armadillo's eigs_gen to find the smallest algebraic eigenvalue of a sparse matrix.

If I request the function for just the smallest eigenvalue the result is incorrect but if I request it for the 2 smallest eigenvalues the result is correct. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;


int
main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;

  sp_mat A(5,5);

  A(1,2) = -1;
  A(2,1) = -1;
  A(3,4) = -1;
  A(4,3) = -1;

  cx_vec eigval;
  cx_mat eigvec;

  eigs_gen(eigval, eigvec, A, 1, "sr");  // find smallest eigenvalue ---> INCORRECT RESULTS
  eigval.print("Smallest real eigval:");

  eigs_gen(eigval, eigvec, A, 2, "sr");  // find 2 smallest eigenvalues ---> ALMOST CORRECT RESULTS 
  eigval.print("Two smallest real eigvals:");

  return 0;
  }
```

My compile command is:

```
 g++ file.cpp -o file.exe -O2 -I/path-to-armadillo/armadillo-4.600.3/include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lblas -llapack -larpack
```

The output is:

```
Armadillo version: 4.600.3 (Off The Reservation)
Smallest real eigval:
    (+1.000e+00,+0.000e+00)
Two smallest real eigvals:
    (-1.000e+00,+0.000e+00)
    (-1.164e-17,+0.000e+00)
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how to overcome this is appreciated.

**Note**: second result is only almost correct because we expect -1, -1 as the two lowest eigenvalues but perhaps repeated eigenvalues are ignored.

**Update**: including a test matrix construction which, after ryan's changes to include the "sa" option to the library, doesn't seem to converge:

```
    #define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
    #include <armadillo>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace arma;
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    size_t l(3), ls(l*l*l);
    sp_mat A = sprandn<sp_mat>(ls, ls, 0.01);
    sp_mat B = A.t()*A;

    vec eigval;
    mat eigvec;
    eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 1, "sa");

    return 0;

    }
```

The matrix sizes of interest are much larger e.g. `ls = 8000 - 27000`, and is not quite the matrix constructed here but I presume the problem should be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the issue here is that you are running `eigs_gen()` (which calls `DNAUPD`) on a symmetric matrix.  ARPACK notes that `DNAUPD` is not meant for symmetric matrices, but does not specify what will happen if you use symmetric matrices anyway:

> NOTE: If the linear operator "OP" is real and symmetric with respect to the real positive semi-definite symmetric matrix B, i.e. B*OP = (OP')*B, then subroutine ssaupd should be used instead.

(from http://www.mathkeisan.com/usersguide/man/dnaupd.html )

I modified the internal Armadillo code to pass "sa" (smallest algebraic) to the ARPACK calls in eigs_sym() (sp_auxlib_meat.hpp), and I was able to obtain the correct eigenvalues.  I've submitted a patch upstream to make "sa" and "la" support available for eigs_sym(), which I think should solve your problem once a new version is released (or at some point in the future).

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a much desired and substantial improvement to the library.

Comment: actually there seem to be convergence issues for the "sa" option, absent for the "lm" option. I've included an update with code, showing a test matrix construction, which doesn't seem to converge for me.

Comment: I would suggest that the problem here is not Armadillo's wrapping of ARPACK but instead the numerical methods that ARPACK uses.  A better investigation of the properties of your input matrix and whether or not the implicitly restarted Arnoldi method is right for your particular matrix is probably the next thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with repeated eigenvalues; if I change the first two matrix elements to

```
A(1,2) = -1.00000001;
A(2,1) = -1.00000001;
```

the expected results are obtained.